# FatalErrorException: KnpSnappyBundle' not found

Tags: class, symfony

i am using symfony2 and i had flowing lines of code in my app\AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
        new FOS\CommentBundle\FOSCommentBundle()
   );

   if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }
    return $bundles;
}
```

and i got error at line number 4 like `"FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\humanfactor\app\AppKernel.php line 4"`

i had also put snappy lib in `vendor` dir from https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle, still i get this error.

KnpSnappyBundle structure

```
Vendor
- KnpSnappyBundle
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the bundle using Composer?

Comment: no, i had download for github